# Failed to delete the a comment of post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I did the function in the controller correctly (as I think), but I could not delete the comment even though the postman returns the response “Comment deleted successfully!.”

When I go to the database, I find that the comment exists in the database and has not been deleted.

I want to know what is wrong with the code. It makes the deletion process not done as it should be.

**comment route**

```
router.delete("/:id/comment/:cid", protectRoute, deleteComment);
```

**controller**

```
const deleteComment = async(req, res) => {
try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    const comment = post.comments.find(
        (comment) => comment._id.toString() === req.params.cid.toString()
    );

    if(!comment){
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Comment not found!" });
    }

    if(comment.userId.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()){
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized to delete comment" });
    }

    if (comment.userId.toString() === req.user._id.toString()) {
        post.comments = post.comments.filter(
            ({ id }) => id !== req.params.cid
        );
    }
        await post.save();
    
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Comment deleted successfully!" });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
}
```

};

**my Post Model**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: 500
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    video: {
        type: String,
        ref: "Upload"
    },
    likes: [{
        // array of user id's
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    }],
    saves: [{
        // array of user id's
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    }],
    comments: [
        {
            id: {
                type: ObjectId,
            },
            userId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User",
                required: true
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            likes: [{
                // array of user id's
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User",
                default: []
            }],
            userProfilePic: {
                type: String,
            },
            username: {
                type: String
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
            },
            replies: [{
                id: {
                    type: ObjectId,
                },
                userId: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "User",
                    required: true
                },
                text: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                userProfilePic: {
                    type: String,
                },
                username: {
                    type: String
                },
                date: {
                    type: Date,
                    default: Date.now()
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true}
)

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

export default Post;
```

Comment: If you add a debug log in the last `if` statement, does it get printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common operation and is typically done with a simple `findOneAndUpdate` like so:

```js
const deleteComment = async(req, res) => {
   try{
       const post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
           {
               _id: req.params.id, //< Match the Post._id
               comments: { //< Must also match comments._id and comments.userId 
                   $elemMatch: {
                       _id: req.params.cid,
                       userId: req.user._id
                   }
               }
           },
           {
               $pull: {
                   'comments': {_id: req.params.cid}, //< Remove the comment from array
               }
           },
           { new : true } //< Return the updated document after the comment removed
       );
       if(!post){ //< Will return null of no document matches
           return res.status(400).json({
               error: "Comment not found!"
           });
       }
       return res.status(200).json({
           message: "Comment deleted successfully!"
       });
   } catch(err){
       console.log(err);
       res.status(500).json({
           error: err.message
       });
   }
}
```

**Edit**: Just noticed you are doing a check for `userId` too so you will need to use `$elemMatch`.

Comment: Thank you @jQueeny your solution is better for me, as I prefer to delete the comment based on the ID rather than delete it based on the index.

Comment: @khayal you're welcome. Looping through an array and converting `ObjectId` to strings and removing based on computed index is a recipe for disaster. MongoDB has a excellent selection of operators to work with arrays to avoid all that. By using mongoose you can do updates in one database query. I never know if someone is looking for an efficient, clean way to solve the problem or they just want their code to work. Happy to help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when comparing two ObjectId instances in MongoDB, you should use the .equals() method instead of == or ===. This is because JavaScript's strict equality rules may not work as expected in this case.

For example, consider the following code snippet

```
    const comment = post.comments.find(
            (comment) => comment._id.toString() === req.params.cid.toString()
        );

    change it to below : 

 const comment = post.comments.find(
          (comment) => comment._id.equals(req.params.cid)
        );
    
    and 

    if (comment.userId.toString() === req.user._id.toString()) {
            post.comments = post.comments.filter(
                ({ id }) => id !== req.params.cid
            );
        } 

to this
    
    if (comment.userId.equals(req.user._id)) {
          // Use .equals() for ObjectId comparison
          post.comments = post.comments.filter(({ _id }) => !_id.equals(req.params.cid));
        } else {
          return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized to delete comment" });
        }
```

I hope this clarifies things for you. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).